# sql server 2012 backup file size expending too much

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, backup

so guys im working with c# and sql server 2012 and every time i do a backup , the size of files.bak are expending so much that the server stop running sometimes
i've tried to use another DB , TrackateOnly , ShrinkFile ... and nothing works !
any ideas please ?.

Comment: What is "so much" ? what kind of backup are you running, is your data on the same drive as the backup file?

Comment: it's a full backup and yes they r on the same drive.
and "so much" that makes the server stop running and i lost a big part of data

Comment: well thats always a bad idea.. so, backup to a different drive. how big is your backup? are you backing up with compression? how much spec is your server - this isnt sounding like a coding issue, more a SQL config issue which isnt a Stackoverflow question